# Plotly animation with factors

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

Converting a num vector to factors yields unexpected results in a plot_ly animation.

> If frame is a numeric variable (or a character string), frames are always ordered in increasing (alphabetical) order; but for factors, the ordering reflects the ordering of the levels [plotly book](https://plotly-book.cpsievert.me/key-frame-animations.html)

With the data set:

```
>str(genTotal)
 data.frame':   1620 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ generation: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ fitness   : num  2.38 2.38 2.38 2.38 21.82 ...
 $ x         : num  0.946 0.946 0.946 0.946 -2.26 ...
 $ x2        : num  -0.0686 -0.0686 -0.0686 -0.0686 2.0935 ...
```

As expected the keyframes are sorted alphabetically:
[image]

---

When converting *generation* to a factor as suggested, suddenly all frames are drawn on top of each other:

```
genTotal$generation <- factor(genTotal$generation, ordered = TRUE)

'data.frame':   1620 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ generation: Factor w/ 81 levels "0","50","100",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ fitness   : num  2.38 2.38 2.38 2.38 21.82 ...
 $ x         : num  0.946 0.946 0.946 0.946 -2.26 ...
 $ x2        : num  -0.0686 -0.0686 -0.0686 -0.0686 2.0935 ...
```

[image]

With the code

```
plot_ly(data = df, x = ~ x, y = ~y, z = ~rastrigin, type = "contour") %>%
  colorbar(title = "Value") %>%
  add_trace(data = genTotal,x=~x,y=~x2,type = "scatter", mode = "markers",
            frame = genTotal$generation,
            inherit = FALSE,
            marker = list(size = 10,
                  color = 'rgba(255, 182, 193, .7)',
                  line = list(color = 'rgba(152, 0, 0, 1)',width = 2))
  )
```

**Questions:**
Why are suddenly all frames drawn on top of each other?

How can I correctly (ordered) animate a plot_ly plot with a numeric frame vector?

Updated: as requested the dput of [genTotal](https://pastebin.com/ytB1xkMG) and [df](https://pastebin.com/uejWJ6p5)

Comment: It is not reproducible. Can you add (using `dput()`) `df` to your post?

Comment: @MLavoie I attached it to the post. Thanks. https://pastebin.com/ytB1xkMG The now posted data is a little bit longer than the once used in the question but never the less the same issue occurs.

Comment: You have provided `genTotal`, but not `df`.

Comment: noticed it. Sorry. here we go https://pastebin.com/uejWJ6p5

Comment: @John Is there something wrong with the `numeric` generation? Or is this a theoretical question? I'm trying to understand why you'd want `factor` over `numeric`.

Comment: @Ameya, because numeric values are ordered in alphabetical order. This means that the generations appear like this 10 -> 100 -> 1000 -> 1100 -> 1150 -> ... -> 200

Comment: Without the contour map, it works....

Comment: It might be a bug (Contour + markers). It does not work with ggplotly() as well.